# How do I make use of OG permissions in the context of menu links?

Tags: organic-groups, users, distributions

I've been trying to get a menu/tab link to display on an OG node (i.e. at `/node/%`) using the following code. This is on Open Atrium.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_menu()
 */

function space_tabs_override_menu() {
  $menus['group/node/%/admin/people'] = array(
      'title' => 'Members',
      'description' => 'Shows the members and the roles of every member in the Space',
      'access callback' => 'check_og_permissions',
      'access arguments' => array(array('manage members')),
  );
  return $menus;
}

/**
 * Check OG permissions, see if there's permission to administer members.
 */
function check_og_permissions($permissions) {
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    // Get the nid
    $nid = $node->nid;
  }
  foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
    if (og_user_access('node', $nid, $permission)) {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

So, after writing the above in a space_tabs_override.module, I'm unable to get the tab to show in, say, `/node/51`. I also tried to browse to the link directly `/group/node/51/admin/people`, and ended up getting an Access Denied page, despite having the required permissions.

Other methods that I've tried is to use the `og_get_entity_groups()` function. Replace the code below

```
  $groups = og_get_entity_groups('node', $nid);
  foreach ($groups as $groups_t) {
    foreach ($groups_t as $gid) {
      foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
        if (og_user_access('node', $gid, $permission)) {
          return TRUE;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Any thoughts?

2015-07-28 : I still haven't found a solution to this question. I should mention I even forced the `'access callback'` to have a value of `TRUE`. That, according to Drupal's docs, should've forced everyone to have access. It seems like there is some hook that systematically takes back the permissions when an object has a certain menu. I tried re-overriding this with `hook_menu_alter`, but that didn't work either. I tried increasing the module weight and that too, didn't work. Really, how should I do this? Speaking of which, I remember there's something called `entity_load()` and `entity_save()`. This is what I'll be trying next. If anyone knows of a better method, please tell me.

Comment: Right when I was posting this question, I soon realize that I got the output of $groups wrong. It returns the entity type as key, and **another array** as value, and in that array is the OG membership ID as key, and the gid I needed.

Comment: I just tried again with the above comment in mind. Didn't work.